# Filter a list of strings based on several possible endings

Tags: python, string, filter

I don't know any python but I need to customize a script a little bit.
There are strings parsed in the script and put to a list (I guess).
Then these strings are filtered based on whether they start with "http". What I want to add is a filter based on their file extension as well. All links ending on `html` or `xml` shall be filtered.

This is the code that filters all hyperlinks:

```
links = filter (lambda x:x.startswith("http://") , links)
```

I don't know the proper syntax to put an OR operator for something like `.endswith(".html) OR .endswith("xml")`

I know this would filter all links ending on `.html` but I also need the `.xml` links.

```
links = filter (lambda x:x.startswith("http://") , links) 
links = filter (lambda x:x.endswith(".html") , links)
```

Comment: Those strings starting with an optional *protocol specification* aren't [hyperlinks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), but [URLs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Answer (score 10):

If you're on at least 2.5, you can pass a tuple of suffixes to `endswith`. Thanks to @hcwhsa for pointing that out:

```
links = filter(lambda x:x.endswith((".html", ".xml")), links)
```

If you're using an earlier version, you can use the `or` operator:

```
links = filter(lambda x:x.endswith(".html") or x.endswith(".xml"), links)
```

Though you will want to lowercase x if you're not sure it's already lowercased.

I would probably do this with a generator expression rather than `filter`, and certainly without successive calls to `filter`:

```
links = [link for link in links if link.startswith('http://') and link.endswith(('.html', '.xml'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way check this with regex

```
>>> import re
>>> c = r"^http://.+\.(html|xml)"
>>> re.match(c, 'hello')
>>> re.match(c, 'http://data.com/word.html')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1d2a100>
```

And the answer will be

```
import re
regex = r"^http://.+\.(html|xml)"
links = filter(lambda x: re.match(regex, x), links)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
links = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".html"), links));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The code from revisions 1 to 3 does not answer `proper syntax to put an OR operator for something like .endswith(".html) OR .endswith("xml")`. It is *very* close to one line presented in the question.